# Can't insert data for 2 foreign key for the same primary key in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I can't insert data in a table where 2 foreign keys refer to one primary key...

The code is as follows:

```
create table Currency 
(
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    Code nvarchar(8) not null,
    Name nvarchar(128) not null,
    Is_Active bit not null default(0),
    Is_Base_Currency bit not null default(0),
    Country_id int foreign key(ID) references Country(ID) not null
)

Create table Currency_rate 
(
    ID int primary key identity(1,1),
    Currency_id int foreign key(ID) references Currency(ID) not null,
    Base_currency_id int foreign key(ID) references Currency(ID) not null,
    Rate decimal(16,6) not null,
    Ts datetime default getDate()
)

Insert into Currency_rate(Currency_id, Base_currency_id, Rate, Ts)
values (1, 1, 121212.212121, '2008-11-11 13:23:44.111'),
       (2, 2, 232323.323232, '2009-11-11 13:23:44.222'),
       (3, 3, 343434.434343, '2010-11-11 13:23:44.333')
```

This is the error I get:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Currency___Curre__239E4DCF". The conflict occurred in database "CryptoCurrencyData", table "dbo.Currency", column 'ID'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Please help me - I can't find any solution surfing the internet...

Thank you all,

Regards,
Elias.H

Comment: hi elias, check Currency table. Currency_Id 1,2 or 3 or non of them exists in the table. Because of that you came across with this error message.

Comment: Those statements would fail... you need to create the tables and then add the constraints. And where is the table Country at? You have it as a FK reference... but haven't given the DDL for it.

The point of your error is that you can't insert into the currentcy_rate where the FK is supposed to reference the Currency table. You need to insert it's parent row in the Currency table first

Comment: You are trying to insert into `currency_rate` without populating `currency` table.  Probably learn what is foreign key and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constrainsts are created to prevent corrupting data by inserting or updating your tables.

In your case, you are trying to insert data which is not existing. You are trying to insert into `Currency_rate` values `ID's` of `Currency` which are not existing in `Currency` table. So this is a whole goal of constraints - prevent corruption of data.

Just for demonstration purposes I've created `Country` table:

```
Create table Country (
  ID int primary key identity(1,1),
  CountryName nvarchar(50)
)
```

Then your first step would be:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Country
(
    --ID - this column value is auto-generated
    CountryName
)
VALUES
(
    -- ID - int
    N'India' -- CountryName - nvarchar
)
, (N'Canada')
, (N'South America')
```

The second step will be:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Currency
(
    --ID - this column value is auto-generated
    Code,
    Name,
    Is_Active,
    Is_Base_Currency,
    Country_id
)
VALUES
(
    -- ID - int
    N'Code1', -- Code - nvarchar
    N'India Currency', -- Name - nvarchar
    0, -- Is_Active - bit
    0, -- Is_Base_Currency - bit
    1 -- Country_id - int
)
, (
 N'Code2', -- Code - nvarchar
    N'Canada Currency', -- Name - nvarchar
    0, -- Is_Active - bit
    0, -- Is_Base_Currency - bit
    2 -- Country_id - int
)
, (
 N'Code3', -- Code - nvarchar
    N'South America Currency', -- Name - nvarchar
    0, -- Is_Active - bit
    0, -- Is_Base_Currency - bit
    3 -- Country_id - int
)
```

And the final step is the following:

```
Insert into Currency_rate(Currency_id,Base_currency_id,Rate,Ts)
values(1,1,121212.212121,'2008-11-11 13:23:44.111'),
(2,2,232323.323232,'2009-11-11 13:23:44.222'),
(3,3,343434.434343,'2010-11-11 13:23:44.333')
```

Comment: thank you for the reply mate , well i had already inserted data into the tables, what I tried is to delete the table currency_rate and re-creating it then inserting data ...That worked for me ... my problem was that i executed a full transact sql code without noticing order of the statements , Again Thanks A Lot